# How do I access a template class member field in a specialised template class in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I am trying to write a template class that has a member of the passed type which is supposed to be used on a method of an specialised template class. Like this:

```
template <class T>
class MyTemplateClass
{
public:
    MyTemplateClass() {}

    void DoSomething()
    {
        DoSomethingWithMember();
    }

    void DoSomethingWithMember() {}

protected:
    T m_member;

};

template<>
class MyTemplateClass<float>
{
public:
    void DoSomethingWithMember()
    {
        printf("Member is %f", m_member);
    }
};
```

So that I can make calls like:

```
MyTemplateClass<float> obj2 = MyTemplateClass<float>();
obj2.DoSomething();
```

The specialised template class won't compile, gives the error:

> "Use of undeclared identifier `m_member`".

Is there a way for the specialised template class to access the original class members without having the code duplicated with the new specialised type? Or any other way to achieve what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: Specializing a class template is not the same as overriding a virtual function, you don't just replace one piece and "inherit" the rest of the class from the primary template. The class template specialization must be a complete class, so if it uses a member called `m_member` it must have a member called `m_member`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you may specialize only one method, something like:

```
template <class T>
class MyTemplateClass
{
public:
    MyTemplateClass(T t) : m_member(t) {}

    void DoSomething() { DoSomethingWithMember(); }

    void DoSomethingWithMember();

protected:
    T m_member;

};

// **Fully** Specialize DoSomethingWithMember for float.
template <>
void MyTemplateClass<float>::DoSomethingWithMember()
{
    std::cout << "Member is " << m_member;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/yvPBcO)

Comment: Great thanks mate! I didn't know it was possible to specialise a single method like that, this should solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

> So that I can make calls like:
>
> ```
> MyTemplateClass<float> obj2 = MyTemplateClass<float>();
> obj2.DoSomething();
> ```
>
> The specialised template class won't compile, gives the error: "Use of undeclared identifier 'm_member'".

That's because the template specialization has no relation to the generic class template. Anything that the specialization needs must be implemented in the specialization. Such as:

```
template<>
class MyTemplateClass<float>
{
   public:
      void DoSomething()
      {
         DoSomethingWithMember();
      }

      void DoSomethingWithMember()
      {
         printf("Member is %f", m_member);
      }

      float m_member;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had already tried explicitly declaring the type as float as you wrote and I saw it worked fine, I just thought this wouldn't be practical because it is bound to generate lots of duplicate code if you have many member fields and/or many types to specialise. The approach suggested by Jarod42 above seems to solve my problem.

Comment: @CaioSabino, you have to use the approach that works best for your needs.